# Detect Skin and Capture Image

Tags: android, c, opencv, image-processing, java-native-interface

**Update 1**

I have an idea what `inRange` function does. But I don't want to apply mask and show the new image with skin color. What I want to do is to know if the image contains skin color and cover larger area.

**What I want to do**

I want to capture a picture whenever finger is detected inside a boundary. Its dimensions are known.

**Struggling points**

1. Manipulate image data in native code.
2. Detecting skin in live camera, so whenever that particular area is focused and skin is detected, snap should be taken

**What I have done**

I am using JNI Layer to perform the operation. I am able to get `Mat` from image data using [this tutorial](http://ibuzzlog.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-do-real-time-image-processing-in.html), but don't know how to manipulate `poutPixels`. The format is `NV21` and I am not sure how to do operations on it.

I need to crop image and then detect if there's skin present in the image. I have successfully cropped the image to the desired dimension, but has no clue to move forward to detect skin. I want this method to return `true` or `false`.

Here is the code:

```
jbyte * pNV21FrameData = env->GetByteArrayElements(NV21FrameData, 0);
jint * poutPixels = env->GetIntArrayElements(outPixels, 0);

Mat mNV(height, width, CV_8UC3, (unsigned char*)pNV21FrameData);
Mat finalImage(height, width, CV_8UC3, (unsigned char*) poutPixels);

jfloat wScale = (float) width/screenWidth;
jfloat hScale = (float) height/screenHeight;

float temp = rectX * wScale;
int x = (int) temp;
temp = rectY * hScale;
int y = (int) temp;

int cW = (int) (width * wScale);
int cH =  (int) (height * hScale);

cH = cH/2;


Rect regionToCrop(x, y, cW, cH);
mNV = mNV(regionToCrop);
finalImage = finalImage(regionToCrop);

//detect skin and return true or false
```

I have read about `inRange` function, but I don't know how to check whether there's skin or not.

**Questions**

1. Am I on the right path to proceed further?
2. The image format I am getting is `NV21`. Is it a `8UC1` or it can be `8UC3` too?
3. How to proceed from here to start detecting skin?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by extracting skin color range and making all pixels equal to `zero`. Below are the steps.

1. Convert the image to HSV

First convert image to `HSV`.

```
Mat mHsv = new Mat(rows, cols, CvType.CV_8UC3);
Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mHsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
```

2. Get range of skin color

Skin color range may vary, but this one is working fine for me.

```
Mat output = new Mat();
Core.inRange(mHsv, new Scalar(0, 0.18*255, 0), new Scalar(25, 0.68*255, 255), output);
```

3. Extract this Skin Range channel

Now extract this channel while making skin pixels equal to `zero`

```
Mat mExtracted = new Mat();
Core.extractChannel(output, mExtracted, 0);
```

Now you have `mExtracted` matrix, in which skin colored pixels are `0` and rests are `255` (or skin color, I am not sure).

4. Get count of zeros

Since `0` now is actually skin color area, what you can do is to define a threshold which suits your need. According to my need, I want skin to cover more than half of the area, so I made my logic accordingly.

```
int n = Core.countNonZero(mExtracted);
int check = (mExtracted.rows() * mExtracted.cols())/2;

if(n >= check && isFocused) {
    //Take picture
}
```

Comment: It's really nice gesture to comment after downvote so other can also learn from your wisdom.